# Understanding Inner blocking size in lapack/plasma

Tags: lapack, blas

I could not get accurate description that aids to my understanding of inner blocking size parameter that is used in many LAPACK routines(such as DGEQRT, DLARFB).

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What don't you understand about the inner blocking size parameter? Right now, it seems like you posed a statement, rather than a question.

Comment: My question in particular is about, how is inner block size different from Block size?

Answer (score 1):

You achieve ideal blocking, if your block fits in your cache. If it does not, it will cost you way more performance. So you have to fit the block size to cache size.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200338/a-cache-efficient-matrix-transpose-program

Comment: This paper has a short introduction: http://suif.stanford.edu/papers/lam-asplos91.pdf

Comment: How is it different from Block size? Why dgemm doesn't use the inner blocking parameter while dgeqrt , dlarfb uses?

Comment: This is a very specific question. I am sorry, but I don't have time to dig deeper. I have a link for you: http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net This is ATLAS a library for automatic tuning, just in case you find that interesting ;-)